# Creating PHP Variables from Associative Array from XML Source

Tags: php, xml, arrays, variables

AHow can I take the below array, coming from a webservice’s XML output, and pull out the [Key]s and their [Value]s and turn them into PHP variables (key matching its value) so I can use them for within PHP scripts. Not having any luck with it, done some research and I am not seeing this layout anywhere. This layout just looks different and I can’t find any examples of this particular layout conversion. Is there a way to pull out specific string data from below such as “user.id” and assign it its value “431349” as php variables ?

```
Array
(
    [RedeemTokenResult] => Array
        (
            [DictionaryEntry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => environmentname
                            [Value] => Staging
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.prc.type
                            [Value] => C
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.country
                            [Value] => United States
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.displayname
                            [Value] => Corporate User
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => sso.testmode
                            [Value] => True
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.region
                            [Value] => Texas
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.par.seg.id
                            [Value] => 1
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.postalcode
                            [Value] => 10001
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => session.expire.timeout
                            [Value] => 60
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.lastname
                            [Value] => User
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.par.classoftrade
                            [Value] => ALL
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.id
                            [Value] => 431349
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.firstname
                            [Value] => Corporate
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.par.id
                            [Value] => 0
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.city
                            [Value] => test
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.address1
                            [Value] => test
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.profile.companyname
                            [Value] => TradeOne
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.email
                            [Value] => nickk@tradeonemktg.com
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.username
                            [Value] => tomsnac
                        )

                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => sso.client.hostname
                            [Value] => 10.1.2.135
                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => session.expire.url
                            [Value] => https://ssostage.tradeonemktg.com/ReturnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fprcstage3.tradeonemktg.com%2fv%2f6%2f1%2fprc%2fsn%2fLogin.aspx%3freturnurl%3d%252fv%252f6%252f1%252fprc%252fsn%252fHome.aspx
                       )

                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => sso.client.ip4
                            [Value] => 10.1.2.135
                        )

                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.timezone
                            [Value] => (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
                        )

                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.culture
                            [Value] => en-US
                        )

                    [24] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.par.seg.marketcode
                            [Value] => NDC
                        )

                    [25] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => user.telephone
                            [Value] => 111111111
                        )

                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => session.expire.time
                            [Value] => 7/23/2012 12:38:28 PM
                        )

                    [27] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => sso.xfer.parameters
                            [Value] => 
                        )

                    [28] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => sso.timestamp
                            [Value] => 7/23/2012 11:38:31 AM
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

========================
THIS IS THE PHP FILE I AM WORKING ON ....

```
<?
require_once "SSO.class.php";

$service = 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX.com/SSO/XXXXXX.asmx'; //Service URl from TradeOne
$affiliate = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Affiliate from TradeOne
$pass = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; //Password secret from TradeOne

$token = $_REQUEST['token'];

$sso = new SSO($pass);
$hashedToken = $sso->encryptToken($token,$salt,$iv);

print $sso->toString();

require_once "../soap_lib/nusoap.php";
$client   = new nusoap_client($service.'?WSDL',true);
$tok = array(
             'affiliate'=>$affiliate,
             'hashedToken'=>$hashedToken
             );

$response = $client->call('RedeemToken',array('parameters'=>$tok)); 

echo '<br /><br />';

function keyValue(&$response) {
  $result = Array();
  foreach($response as $row) {
    $result[$row['Key']] = $row['Value'];
  }
  $a = $result;
}

keyValue($a['RedeemTokenResult']['DictionaryEntry']);



var_dump($response);

?>
```

This is the last edit I did and resulted in:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /xxxx/xxxx/xx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxxxx.php on line 51
array(1) { ["RedeemTokenResult"]=> array(1) { ["DictionaryEntry"]=> NULL } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array instead of trying to create a bunch of variables. You can create a dynamic, multidimensional array like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach( $response['RedeemTokenResult']['DictionaryEntry'] as $item) {
    $keys = explode( '.', $item['Key']);
    $array_name = array_shift( $keys); // Get name of the array
    $temp =& $result[$array_name];
    foreach( $keys as $key)
    {           
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = trim( $item['Value']);
}
```

This produces a single `$result` array that [looks like](http://viper-7.com/QW6NkZ):

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [telephone] => 111111111
        )

    [session] => Array
        (
            [expire] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 7/23/2012 12:38:28 PM
                )

        )

    [sso] => Array
        (
            [xfer] => Array
                (
                    [parameters] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Now you can grab elements like:

```
echo $result['user']['telephone'];
echo $result['session']['expire']['time'];
```

Comment: i just wonder - why do you add space before first argument of function? i never see that kind of formating

Comment: I still get the warning error: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @James - After `$response = $client->call('RedeemToken',array('parameters'=>$tok));`, add the code in my answer.

Comment: Both of your codes are working now. @nickb - I am assuming that your code works well because it is pulling out the decimals out of the <KEY> names so I can use them as variables.

Comment: @peter - I am "assuming" that your code is only making an array that and not true variables because of the decimals in the <KEY> names? Guys, thanks a lot for being patient with me - especially you Peter and your quick responses. This is the way I learn and trust me I learn! If I have any more questions I will probably post it as another question since this one is answered.

Comment: @James Yes it does that without creating a huge number of variables - In fact, it creates only one array, and allows you to properly call the values without the periods. Also, if the question is answered, you should mark one of the answers as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @nickb Thanks again! I marked it answered. Still learning on here. I really like this site! Thanks to both you and Peter!

Answer (score 1):

```
function keyvalue(&$array) {
  $result = Array();
  foreach($array as $row) {
    $result[$row['Key']] = $row['Value'];
  }
  $array = $result;
}

keyValue($array['RedeemTokenResult']['DictionaryEntry']);
```

Comment: @Matt won't work [version A](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9ACKJF) - [version B](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0c8gzJ)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I added the above script and I get this warning error:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxx/xxxxx.php on line 41 - line 41 being "foreach($array as $row) {"

Comment: Just being nosy - you're over-writing the incoming array with your processed one. Is there a reason you've done it that way, rather than returning `$result`?

Comment: @andrewsi just to keep code tidy. @James make use argument of `keyValue` is an array.

Comment: The above Array is what I am given from a webservice handshake using nuSOAP.

Comment: I belevie you have some misprint. As i said make sure function argument is an array. Debug your code using `var_dump`

Comment: I am really new at this array stuff, so please forgive me for being a noob! Here is what I have done so far:

function keyValue(&$array) {
  $result = Array();
  foreach($array as $row) {
    $result[$row['Key']] = $row['Value'];
  }
  $array = $result;
}

keyValue($array['RedeemTokenResult']['DictionaryEntry']);

var_dump($array);


RESULTS:

Comment: This is where I am getting this array from: "$result = $client->call('RedeemToken',array('parameters'=>$tok));" I don't know if I am understanding how to make sure function argument 'keyValue' is an array. Please forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: This is what var_dump tells me: "array(1) { ["RedeemTokenResult"]=> array(1) { ["DictionaryEntry"]=> NULL } } "

Comment: yeah DictionaryEntry is empty. you need to pass array as argument not `NULL` value

Comment: and how does a novice do that?

Comment: Where on the web is a good place to find a paid consultant? I need help with this and it apparently is above me.

Comment: @James i would like to help you using Stackoverflow chat, but you need 20 reputation to join chat rooms. :(

Comment: Thanks Peter! I will add to my question above to give full picture of the php file I am using.

Comment: var_dump($response); was var_dump($a); when that particular warning was created. I am still trying to get used to StakExchange. Sorry! It will not let me edit it. I changed some of it to $response to see if it would produce correct arrays. still as you can see not working. Thanks again!

Comment: Try this - https://gist.github.com/3430393 - i don't know why did u start messing with my function :D

Comment: @peter - that worked! I just cannot figure out how to get the variables since each <KEY> name has decimals in it. I tried nickb and his seems to effectively pullout the decimals and separate into arrays that I can create a variable from. Any thoughts! But I do have a working solution now. Thanks to both of you!